# Typo3 11.5 clears cache after user navigates to other language

Tags: php, caching, typo3

We have upgraded from Typo3 8.7 to 11.5 and caching is not working anymore like on the old instance.

It seems like the caching settings in LocalConfiguration.php is how the installer created it. Not sure if extensions can influence this caching behaviour.

If I request a page, Time-to-First-Byte is > 1.2s. The second request is roughly 300ms. Switching the language of the site (en, it, de, fr), the page is slow again, and a second request is 4 times faster. Switching back to the initial page shows first again the slow behaviour and with a second request the faster.

It looks like hitting the language switcher clears the cache.

What I have tried so far:

- Default settings in LocalConfiguration.php (all Typo3DatabaseBackend caches)
- DB Optimization
- Cache warming

What else can we try?

Comment: Which kind of language switcher do you use? For switching back, are you using the language switcher or requesting the old URL (via language switcher, there might be `L=0`set in the URL, while the first request was done without any L-parameter => two different versions of the page)

Comment: Thanks, @JulianHofmann, there is no L=X request parameter visible in the URL (browser). 

I see  `tx_realurl_enable = 1` but I don't think realurl is installed since it is not supported in typo3 11.5.

There is also `linkVars = L(0-4)`, `uniqueLinkVars = 1`,  `defaultGetVars.L = 0` set.

Comment: Does this happen only when switching back to the default language or with each change of the language?

Comment: It will also play a role if and on which domain you are logged into the backend. Best compare with another browser/private tab where you are not logged in.

Comment: I am not logged in to the backend. and it happens with every switch of the language. Actually, it even happens also when I manually "adjust" the URLs and do not click them in the browser.

Comment: As you mentioned about the languages the translation mode would be interesting.
Then I'd enable the admin panel and compare the SQL for each request, the SQL can be shown in the admin Panel.

Comment: Any news on this? We have the exact same behavior after upgrading from v9 to v11 and don't know exactly what is causing this.

Comment: It's a bug and it's listed here - https://forge.typo3.org/issues/98126?next_issue_id=98124&prev_issue_id=98129 @dermatthis has added more information and it looks like currently it can only be fixed with a cache hook.